# Границы придаточного определительного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, придаточное-предложение

Бывают песни другие, **мотив которых(,) грустный**, **протяжный(,)** западает в душу **не сразу() и его порой** не повторишь сам, но что-то очень большое остается на душе после такой песни.

Корреспонденция Константина Симонова "Из записок о Южной Сербии",
опубликованная в газете "Красная звезда" 19 декабря 1944 года

Верно ли в этом случае автор определил границы придаточного определительного предложения и чем объясняется постановка запятых на границах ряда грустный, протяжный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки поставлены **верно**:

*Бывают песни другие, // **мотив которых**, грустный, протяжный, западает в душу не сразу **и его (= мотив которых)** порой не повторишь сам, // но что-то очень большое остается на душе после такой песни.*

1. **Сложное предложение**,  четыре предикативные основы, два **блока**. Граница между блоками перед союзом ***НО***.

В первой части СПП, два **однородных определительных** придаточных, связанных союзом ***И***. Паузы нет.

Союзное слово **"которых"** и местоимение **"его"**  в значении **"мотив которых"**.

2. Ряд ***"грустный, протяжный"*** расположен **на расстоянии** от определяемого существительного "мотив" и поэтому **обособляется.**  Интонация **перечислительная**.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Иногда бывают такие конструкции, которые вызывают сомнения, особенно там, где надо подставлять знак =.)

Comment: Спасибо, Иван, за очередной интересный вопрос. Мне пришлось над ним подумать, такие конструкции мне не встречались раньше.  Честно говоря,  импровизированное решение.  Я думала, что вопрос вызовет интерес и будут другие варианты. Но вот нет.  И все же загадка остается) И задавайте еще вопросы, синтаксис – это в грамматике действительно интересно. Как бы страна особенной гармонии.